# C Array signing value

Tags: c

i'm new in C and I really can't figure it out why this code print on cities[0] and cities[1] value of the last signed string. Can someone help me ?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  char str[50];
  char *cities[42];

  fgets(str,50,stdin);
  cities[0] = str;

  fgets(str,50,stdin);
  cities[1] = str;

  printf("end\n");
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: You're assigning the address of (the first element of) `str` to the `cities` elements. The contents of `str` get overwritten by `fgets`.

Comment: Because you are writing the buffer pointer to both array elements: its content is the same. Suggest `cities[0] = strdup(str);` etc.

Comment: Thank you :) I finally understand what's going on :) 

Thank you

Comment: BTW `int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;` --> `int main(void){`